# Word VBA Loop through bookmarks of similar names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a userform that allows users to insert an intentionally blank page after the cover page if they need to print the document. I can get this to work just fine when i only need to insert 1 or 2 blank pages throughout the document, however I now have a new document where i need to insert a total of 14 blank pages if the userform combobox is changed to "Printable Format"

The code i use for the current document is below as reference but I think for adding so many blank pages i'm better to use a loop or find instead of this.

All of my bookmarks for where blank pages are to be added are named "Print" with sequential numbers (ie. "Print 1", Print2" etc) so i was hoping to be able to search through the document for all bookmarks containing the name "Print" but i can't seem to figure it out!

````
Dim answer As Integer
Dim BMBreak As Range
Dim BMBreak2 As Range

With ActiveDocument

    'Insert bookmarks applicable to Printable Format
    If CbxPrint.Value = "Printable Format" Then

        answer = MsgBox("You have changed the document to Printable Format." & vbNewLine _
                & "This will add intentionally blank pages throughout the document " & vbNewLine _
                & "Do you wish to continue?", vbOKCancel, "WARNING")

        If answer = vbOK Then

            'Intentional blank page after title page
            Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Print1").Range

                BMRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                BMRange.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
                BMRange.Text = "THIS PAGE IS INTENTIONALLY BLANK"
                BMRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 36
                BMRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Print1", BMRange

                With BMRange
                    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
                End With

                With ActiveDocument.Sections(3)
                    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
                    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
                End With

                With ActiveDocument.Sections(2)
                    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
                    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
                    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
                    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
                End With ```
````

Comment: You may be over complicating the solution.  It could be that you do not need to add bookmarks.  Instead take a look at the different types of section break that are available.  It may be that changing you section breaks to Even page or Odd page maybe the better solution.   (Layout.Breaks..)

Answer (score 0):

Code like the following will process any number of Print# bookmarks (presently limited to 20, which need not all exist):

```
Dim i As Long, BMRange As Range
With ActiveDocument
  If CbxPrint.Value = "Printable Format" Then
    If MsgBox("You have changed the document to Printable Format." & vbCr & _
      "This will add intentionally blank pages throughout the document " & vbCr _
      & "Do you wish to continue?", vbOKCancel, "WARNING") = vbOK Then
    'Process bookmarks applicable to Printable Format
      For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
        If .Bookmarks.Exists("Print" & i) = True Then
          'Intentional blank page
          Set BMRange = .Bookmarks("Print" & i).Range
          With BMRange
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            .Start = .Start - 1
            .Sections.Last.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
            .Sections.Last.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
            With .Sections.First
              .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
              .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
              .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
              .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
              .Range.InsertBefore "THIS PAGE IS INTENTIONALLY BLANK"
              .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 36
              .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            End With
            .Start = .Start - 1
            .Bookmarks.Add "Print" & i, .Duplicate
          End With
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End If
End With
```